# Is there an easy way to run DataFrames::by in parallel?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a large dataframe I want to compute on in parallel. The call I want to parallelize is

```
df = by(df, [:Chromosome], some_func)
```

Is there a way to easily parallelize this? Preferably without any copying.

Also, I guess the kinds of parallelization used should be different depending on the size of the groups created by by.

---

Minimal reproducible example to use in answers:

```
using DataFrames, CSV, Pkg
iris = CSV.read(joinpath(Pkg.dir("DataFrames"), "test/data/iris.csv"))
iris_count = by(iris, [:Species], nrow)
```

Comment: The actual implementation would depend on if you want to use mulithreading or multiple processes. In general you can run `groupby` in one process, then apply the function you want to created groups in parallel, and finally combine the results again in one process.

Comment: Will try after the weekend and report whether I got a successful result :)

Comment: Of course this will help if apply part is computationally expensive, as currently split and combine steps in split-apply-combine pipeline do not support parallel processing in DataFrames.jl. In general JuliaDB.jl is a package designed with full support of out-of-core workflows.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows run in console (adjust to the number of cores/threads you have):

```
$ set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
$ julia
```

On Linux run in console:

```
$ export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
$ julia
```

Now check if it works:

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
4
```

Run the code below (I update your code to match Julia 1.0):

```
using CSV, DataFrames, BenchmarkTools
iris = CSV.read(joinpath(dirname(pathof(DataFrames)),"..","test/data/iris.csv"))
iris.PetalType = iris.PetalWidth .> 2;  #add an additional column for testing
```

Let us define some function that operates on a part of a `DataFrame`

```
 function nrow2(df::AbstractDataFrame)
     val = nrow(df) 
     #do something much more complicated...
     val
 end
```

Now the most complicated part of the puzzle comes:

```
function par_by(df::AbstractDataFrame,f::Function,cols::Symbol...;block_size=40)
    #f needs to be precompiled - we precompile using the first row of the DataFrame.
    #If try to do it within @thread macro
    #Julia will crash in most ugly and unexpected ways
    #if you comment out this line you can observe a different crash with every run
    by(view(df,1:1),[cols...],f);

    nr = nrow(df)
    local dfs = DataFrame()
    blocks = Int(ceil(nr/block_size))
    s = Threads.SpinLock()
    Threads.@threads for block in 1:blocks
        startix = (block-1)*block_size+1
        endix = min(block*block_size,nr)
        rv= by(view(df,startix:endix), [cols...], f)
        Threads.lock(s)
        if nrow(dfs) == 0  
            dfs = rv
        else 
            append!(dfs,rv)
        end
        Threads.unlock(s)
    end
    dfs
end
```

Let's test it and aggregate the results

```
julia> res = par_by(iris,nrow2,:Species)
6×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species    │ x1    │
│     │ String     │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ versicolor │ 20    │
│ 2   │ virginica  │ 20    │
│ 3   │ setosa     │ 10    │
│ 4   │ versicolor │ 30    │
│ 5   │ virginica  │ 30    │
│ 6   │ setosa     │ 40    │


julia> by(res, :Species) do df;DataFrame(x1=sum(df.x1));end
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species    │ x1    │
│     │ String     │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ setosa     │ 50    │
│ 2   │ versicolor │ 50    │
│ 3   │ virginica  │ 50    │
```

The `par_by` also supports multiple columns

```
julia> res = par_by(iris,nrow2,:Species,:PetalType)
8×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ Species   │ PetalType │ x1    │
│     │ String    │ Bool      │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────────┼───────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ setosa    │ false     │ 40    │
⋮
│ 7   │ virginica │ true      │ 13    │
│ 8   │ virginica │ false     │ 17    │
```

@Bogumił Kamiński commented that it is reasonable to use `groupby()` before threading. Unless for some reason `groupby` cost is to high (requires full scan) this is the recommended way - makes the aggregation simpler.

```
 ress = DataFrame(Species=String[],count=Int[])
 for group in groupby(iris,:Species)
     r = par_by(group,nrow2,:Species,block_size=15)
     push!(ress,[r.Species[1],sum(r.x1)])
 end 


 julia> ress
 3×2 DataFrame
 │ Row │ Species    │ count │
 │     │ String     │ Int64 │
 ├─────┼────────────┼───────┤
 │ 1   │ setosa     │ 50    │
 │ 2   │ versicolor │ 50    │
 │ 3   │ virginica  │ 50    │
```

Note that in the example above are only three groups so we parallelize over each group. However, if you have big number of groups you could consider running:

```
function par_by2(df::AbstractDataFrame,f::Function,cols::Symbol...)
    res = NamedTuple[]
    s = Threads.SpinLock()
    groups = groupby(df,[cols...])
    f(view(groups[1],1:1));
    Threads.@threads for g in 1:length(groups)
        rv= f(groups[g])
        Threads.lock(s)
        key=tuple([groups[g][cc][1] for cc in cols]...)
        push!(res,(key=key,val=rv))
        Threads.unlock(s)
    end
    res
end

julia> iris.PetalType = iris.PetalWidth .> 2;

julia> par_by2(iris,nrow2,:Species,:PetalType)
4-element Array{NamedTuple,1}:
 (key = ("setosa", false), val = 50)
 (key = ("versicolor", false), val = 50)
 (key = ("virginica", true), val = 23)
 (key = ("virginica", false), val = 27)
```

Let me know if it worked for you. 
Since more people might have similar problem I will make this code into a Julia package (and that is why I kept this code to be very general)

Comment: `julia -p 4` gives four worker processes not the threads. For your problem I would recommend look into threads first. Threads can work wit the same memory across CPUs. On the other hand multi-processing requires copying data among processes (or you can use `SharedArrays.jl` but then again it's about splitting data among processes)

Comment: It's not copying memory (look at the usage of `view()`). I made those examples exactly having in mind be a canonical answer to  common problem.

Comment: And here it is - I updated the code to include support for any number of columns. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Now par_by2 does not return a dataframe, unlike the original by. It returns an `array{NamedTuple}`. par_by works though :)

Comment: Your `par_by` gives different results than regular `by` on some of my data. This is not strange as it seems to cut the data into blocks and then running the groupby on them which would give wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Start julia with `julia -p 4` then run

```
using CSV, DataFrames

iris = CSV.read(joinpath(dirname(pathof(DataFrames)),"..","test/data/iris.csv"))

g = groupby(iris, :Species)

pmap(nrow, [i for i in g])
```

This will run groupby in parallel.

Comment: This uses multiprocessing: (1) the data must be copied among processes (at least for each group), and (2) you need to make sure that your custom functions and data are present at the remote processes (e.g. using `@everywhere`). On the other hand it scales to clusters (threading scales o only one machine).